# Underscore _.map() method and object constructor

Tags: object, constructor, underscore.js

I'm going to explain this as best as I can.
First of all I am using Underscore.
I am making a very simple data visualization for a set of data.

At this point, I;m simply trying to get the data that I want.

Before I explain further, here is a snippet of my data.

```
var data =

[
    {
        "id": "a09f4967-10a8-53c1-b53f-8e49ee255734",
        "type": "chat",
        "requested_by": "zoidberg@example.com",
        "initial_message": "And here I am using my own lungs like a sucker.",
        "created_at": 1420190706057,
        "page_url": "http://www.awesome3ftcakes.com/contact-us.html",
        "referrer_url": "http://www.bing.com/search?q=top",
        "entry_url": "unknown",
        "ip_address": "132.145.187.8",
        "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.4.6",
        "latitude": 51.339695,
        "longitude": 12.373075,
        "chat_waittime": 10,
        "chat_duration": 205,
        "survey_score": 30,
        "language_code": "",
        "transcript": [
            {
                "date": 1420190706057,
                "alias": "Zoidberg",
                "message": "And here I am using my own lungs like a sucker."
            },
            {
                "id": "jerome@awesome3ftcakes.com",
                "date": 1420190733788,
                "alias": "Jerome",
                "message": "Hi. I'm Troy McClure. You may remember me from such self-help tapes as \"Smoke Yourself Thin\" and \"Get Some Confidence, Stupid!\""
            }
        ]
    }, ...
```

So, here is my problem:

I create a constructor function like so:

```
function ChatSession(data) {

    this.duration = data.chat_duration;
    this.score = data.survey_score;
    this.repId = data.transcript;
};


var mappedObjects = _.map(data, function(chatSessionData) {
    return new ChatSession(chatSessionData)
});

console.log(mappedObjects);
```

[console.log view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fjQb.png)

If you look at the image ^ above, you will see that I get my new ChatSession objects, with duration, then transcript, and then score.

Where I run into a problem is this... I want to be more specific in the transcript. I want to reference the second object in the transcript array, and get specifically either the id or the alias.

I've tried many things and basically get the same error. For example I tried this:

```
function ChatSession(data) {

    this.duration = data.chat_duration;
    this.score = data.survey_score;
    this.repId = data.transcript[1].id;
};
```

and I get the following message in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Even if I take the id portion off, the error still says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm banging my head against the wall.

Answer (score 1):

The one or more data objects in your collection has `transcript` as `undefined`. Use constructor below to detect which data objects in collection with missed `transcript` property.

```
function ChatSession(data) {
    this.duration = data.chat_duration;
    this.score = data.survey_score;
    this.repId = (data.transcript && data.transcript[1]) ? data.transcript[1].id : undefined;
};
```